# Where did the Ubuntu Touch files for the Galaxy Nexus Toro go?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, galaxy-nexus

I may have missed something but the only link I found no longer has the ubuntu touch files for the galaxy nexus Toro.

Could anyone give me a link to where I can download the `.zip` files for this version please?

Comment: Current status can be found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/toro (not being actively maintained)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much searching you actually did. Heres the [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=38294870) to the image, although it doesn't seem to be maintained or updated since February so use at your own risk.

I havent seen anything recently regarding the Galaxy Nexus Toro so that may be the only port that has been done.

Comment: i did see that sight, but the download link is broken, do you know of a different source for these files?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, They were no longer being maintained and I haven't heard of any other ports or anyone else maintaining the package. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file here on androidmeter.com:

- http://androidmeter.com/toro_ubuntu.zip